# Why is the destructor called before the move constructor when returning a temporary (rvalue)

Tags: c++, move-semantics, temporary

I suspect I don't understand something about move semantics. Given the following code I would expect the debugger (MSVC2010SP1) to call Proxy's members in the following order:

- `Proxy(Resource*)` constructing the temporary in `getProxy`
- `Proxy(Proxy&& other)` move constructing `p`
- `~Proxy()` destructing the empty shell of the temporary that got its guts taken by move
- `~Proxy() p` goes out of scope

  ```
  class Resource
  {
      void open(){}
  public:
      void close(){}
      Proxy && getProxy();
  };
  class Proxy
  {
      Resource *pResource_;
      Proxy(const Proxy& other); //disabled
      Proxy& operator=(const Proxy& other); //disabled
  public:
      Proxy(Resource *pResource):pResource_(pResource){}
      Proxy(Proxy&& other):pResource_(other.pResource_){other.pResource_ = nullptr;}
      ~Proxy()
      {
          if(pResource_)
              pResource_->close();
          pResource_ = nullptr;
      }
  };

  Proxy && Resource::getProxy()
  {
          open();
          return Proxy(this);
  }

  //somewhere else, lets say in main()
  Resource r;
  {
      auto p = r.getProxy(); 
  }   // p goes out of scope
  ```

Instead the order is:

- `Proxy(Proxy*)`
- `~Proxy()`              //this already calls `close()` earlier than expected
- `Proxy(Proxy&& other)`  //moving after destruction gives `p.pResource_` a value of `nullptr`
- `~Proxy()`              //`p` goes out of scope

This makes no sense to me. What I'm trying to do is track the lifetime of the proxy class passing the job of closing the resource via the move constructor from one object to another.

Comment: We don't know how you create/return one of these objects, but I would suspect you return a reference to a local, which is a nono

Comment: @PlasmaHH sorry didn't post all the code (need coffee)

Comment: You should almost never use an rvalue-reference as a return type.  Just use the class type to allow return via move constructor.

Comment: is it guaranteed that the returned value will be move constructed?

Comment: @PorkyBrain: If you return a temporary or a function-local class variable or a `std::move(something)` and the return type is a class type, then either the returned value will be move constructed or the copy/move will be elided entirely.

Comment: @PorkyBrain Nope. It's returned by reference. Returning it like this will certainly not move it. If you want the object to be moved, return by value.

Comment: you guys are awesome, this is the fastest I have ever been helped! Thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getProxy()` returns a reference to a temporary, which goes out of scope at function end and results in a dangling reference.

Comment: ah I think I understand, so by declaring the return type Proxy&& I'm basically returning a Proxy& with the special privilege that it can get its guts taken by move?

Comment: @PorkyBrain Pretty much. You're still returning a reference, so it has to be backed by something. In your case, you should just return by value. Returning an rvalue ref. would make sense if e.g. you wanted to move something out of the object (`return std::move(this->something);`).

Answer (score 2):

Returning by rvalue reference doesn't actually cause anything to be moved. It just returns by reference. However, it's different to returning an lvalue reference because an expression calling a function that returns an rvalue reference is an xvalue (as opposed to an lvalue). The xvalue (as a subset of rvalue expressions) can then be moved from. If you wanted to move from the returned object of a function returning lvalue reference, you would have to use `std::move` to make it an rvalue.

You very rarely will want to actually return an rvalue reference. The only vaguely common use for it is to allow a private member of an object to be moved from. If you want an object to be moved when you return it from a function, just return it by value. In your case, if the return type of `getProxy` was just `Proxy`, the temporary would be moved from into the returned object and then that would be moved from into `p` (save for any elision).

As you have it, your temporary object (contructed by `Proxy(this)`) is destroyed at the end of the `return` statement - this is the first call of the destructor. The returned reference is now referencing an invalid object and `p` is constructed by moving from this invalid reference. That gives you undefined behaviour.